# En aplicación con Cakephp 1.2 , obtener un array mediante una llamada ajax a una función que está en un controller que tiene helper Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

La aplicación usa cakephp 1.2.
Lo que pretendo es comprobar, al momento de guardar, si un elemento introducido en un formulario ya está en bbdd. Para ello hago una llamada ajax a la función del controller. La llamada llega y la función introduce en un array los valores de bbdd, correctamente. El problema es que no consigo recibirlo en la función que hace la llamada.Tanto si pongo return, como si no, obtengo un objeto que no es lo que necesito.
La función que hace la llamada es ésta:

```
function buscarProveedoresEnConsulta() {
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->webroot.'consultas/proveedoresEnConsulta/';?>' + ID_CONSULTA, {
            method: 'get',
            asynchronous:false,
            onSuccess:function(request) {
                console.log("RSO Object.keys(request): " + Object.keys(request));
                return request; 
            }
        });     
    }
```

La función en el controller es ésta:

```
function proveedoresEnConsulta ($ID_CONSULTA) {
        $proveedoresEnConsulta = array();
        $cAux2 = $this->ProveedorConsulta->findAllByIdConsulta($ID_CONSULTA);
        foreach($cAux2 as $consulta) {
            $proveedoresEnConsulta[] = json_encode($consulta['Proveedor']['ID']);
        }
        $this->log("RSO Array proveedoresEnConsulta: " . print_r($proveedoresEnConsulta, true));
        return json_encode($proveedoresEnConsulta);
    }
```

En el archivo error.log obtengo el resultado esperado:

```
2021-02-23 10:11:03 Error: RSO Array proveedoresEnConsulta: Array
(
    [0] => "900"
    [1] => "547"
    [2] => "104"
)
```

Pero el console.log arroja unos valores que no comprendo:

```
RSO Object.keys(request): request,transport,readyState,status,statusText,responseText,headerJSON,responseXML,responseJSON,initialize,getStatus,getStatusText,getHeader,getAllHeaders,getResponseHeader,getAllResponseHeaders,_getHeaderJSON,_getResponseJSON
```

Parece que el ajax del controller es un helper, que no llego a comprender, y que devuelve un layout que tampoco consigo entender.
Por favor, podrían ayudarme a obtener el array $proveedoresEnConsulta que se produce en la función del controller "proveedoresEnConsulta ($ID_CONSULTA)".
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No he trabajado con cakephp, pero lo que espera capturar una llamada AJAX es un `echo` (o similar) desde el servidor. Yo probaría a cambiar el `return` de tu función PHP para escupir  `json_encode($proveedoresEnConsulta)` con un `echo`

Comment: Gracias @phpMyGuel,  el echo me imprime el array al principio del responseText del objeto, pero me sigue devolviendo un objeto enorme, que ahora incluye el array. Es una solución, aunque muy costosa. Lo ideal sería que me devolviera el array y nada más.

Comment: Creo que me he explicado fatal: cuando hago un console.log(request.responseText); obtengo el array que he enviado como echo, seguido de una página completa: ["\"900\"","\"547\"","\"104\""]<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://....(aquí todo el código de una página).

Comment: Vale, ahora si que comienzo a entenderte. ¿Es posible que en el constructor de la clase donde está la función a la que llamas desde AJAX estés cargando alguna Vista?

Comment: Parece que Cakephp usa algo que llama helpers que envían código a las vistas, y que hay un helper llamado Ajax, con un comportamiento predeterminado, pero no sé cómo acceder a esta configuración, no consigo entender la documentación de Cakephp 1.2. Podría extraer el array de esta respuesta, pero es muy costoso, y esta es una operación muy frecuente en la aplicación, tengo que encontrar algo más liviano, más directo.

Comment: Te invito a pasarte por https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol. Creo que desde ahí podremos hablarlo mejor ^^